# How do I split a file into lines by spaces using the Tkinter library in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to split a file into lines by spaces, using Tkinter's Text widget and I tried this:

```
Text = Text.split(sep='\n'),
```

but I get the error "type object 'Text' has no attribute 'split'" please, tell me how to solve this

I tried to convert Text to string but no result

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to convert spaces into new line characters. I am not aware of a `Tkinter.Text` method that can achieve that, but you could save the Text widgets text to a `python` `string` then use python's string methods to do this. Then use the python string to set the value of the Text widget.

Comment: The error obviously tells you that class `Text` does not have `split()` function.  You need to call `.split()` on a string instead. Also don't use class name as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data out of the text widget with the `get` method, and then call `split` on what is returned.

```
data = the_text_widget.get("1.0", "end-1c")
Text = data.split(sep="\n")
```